# Php - send encrypted mail with multiple, encrypted attachments, readable for Outlook

Tags: php, email, encryption, html-email, email-attachments

Can anyone please explain how to encrypt mime-mail with multiple attachments, readable for Outlook? I currently build a multipart mail, that is read correctly by Outlook, but if I encrypt that multipart-headers + body with openssl_pkcs7_encrypt(), Outlook only reads the (html)-body and fails to separate the attachments. It then states the first attachment as unreadable.

Structure is

```
    To: you@example.com
    From: me@example.com
    Reply-To: me@example.com
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="mx-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa"
    This is a multi-part message in MIME format

    --mx-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="rel-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa";

    --rel-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;

    [html-content here...]

    --rel-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
    Content-Type: image/jpg; name="Image.jpg"
    Content-ID: img1
    Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Image.jpg"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    [related base64-encoded JPEG...]

    --rel-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
    --mx-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="A_PDF.pdf"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="A_PDF.pdf"

    [base64-encoded PDF...]

    --mx-2041315b16859f651fe7575c5949d1aa
```

Comment: If all you care about is transport level encryption (prevents man in the middle attacks) you should read up on [SMTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS), if you want to encrypt the contents of the e-mail you should only care about encrypting the body part of the MIME block, read this related question on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106303/how-to-encrypt-data-in-email-body-sent-by-offline-app-and-decrypt-on-server)